# doctrine dql custom join with on

Tags: join, doctrine, foreign-keys, dql

i have tables witch have **no foreign key** and no relation in **doctrine**
but logically they are related by some fields.
how can i join them with DQL and Query over them.
can i use `ON` between their fields?

Answer (score 2):

as I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/6BZZQQwoi3w):

> Custom left join with unrelated models:
>   This is unfortunately not possible with the Doctrine 1 ORM. I think you would be best served to work directly with the database in this case.